# Why is Github API rendering my markdown incorrectly?

Tags: github, github-api

I am doing this:

```
curl -X POST -d @a.md  https://api.github.com/markdown/raw --header "Content-Type:text/x-markdown" > a.html
```

a.md

```
# Hello, world!
### This is markdown!
How are you doing?
```

a.html

```
<h1>
<a id="user-content-hello-world-this-is-markdownhow-are-you-doing" class="anchor" href="#hello-world-this-is-markdownhow-are-you-doing" aria-hidden="true"><span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Hello, world!### This is markdown!How are you doing?</h1>
```

Rendered a.html

> ## Hello, world!### This is markdown!How are you
>   doing?

I even tried adding Windows-style cr/lf, did not help:

```
CR=$(printf '\r')
sed "s/\$/$CR/" a.md > b.md
```

What am I doing wrong?

The docs for Github API for Markdown are [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/#render-a-markdown-document-in-raw-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Couple things...

First, your a.md file needs to look like this:

```
{
    "text" : "# Hello, world!\n
    ### This is markdown!\n
    How are you doing?",
    "mode" : "markdown",
    "context" : "none"
}
```

Second, you are calling markdown raw, which won't help, the following CURL request worked for me:

```
curl --data @a.md https://api.github.com/markdown > a.html
```

The output for me from that command with that file is:

```
<h1>
<a id="user-content-hello-world" class="anchor" href="#hello-world" aria-hidden="true"><span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Hello, world!</h1>

<h3>
<a id="user-content-this-is-markdown" class="anchor" href="#this-is-markdown" aria-hidden="true"><span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>This is markdown!</h3>

<p>How are you doing?</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It worked. One small correction, "###" needs to begin at column 1.

Comment: So, how come the raw mode did not work? I still need to make it work

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/x-markdown" https://api.github.com/markdown/raw --data @a.md > a.html` where a.md is a raw md file. What are you using this for? Because even that command used on an actual README I have is a pretty bleh looking render.

Comment: Is there any way to remove `a` and `span` inside h1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `--data-binary` instead of `--data` and then you don't have to use JSON. So from your example:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @a.md  https://api.github.com/markdown/raw --header "Content-Type:text/x-markdown" > a.html
```